# Reducing memory waste when creating similar objects

Tags: c++, class

Suppose I have an object and I want to make many copies of it that will mostly be the same but with slight variations. What is the proper way to share the common properties between these objects without excessive copying?

For a concrete example

```
class A:
{
   BigData bd;
   LittleData ld;       

   A(const BigData& bd, LittleData ld): bd {bd}, ld {ld} {}
};
```

I start with an initial object A, and make numerous copies of A with different little data, but the same big data. I would have liked to use the static keyword for the big data, but I can't because the big data depends on initialization.

Comment: [`std::shared_ptr<BigData>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)? The creation of all of your `A` objects would somehow have to be coordinated though.

Comment: Research "copy on write".

Comment: Strikes me that `BigData` and `LittleData` don't really belong in the same class. Especially since you were considering making `BigData` static. Maybe some refactorization is required.

Comment: You might consider the [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) as well. We don't know enough just here to determine which of the options would be best.

Comment: You haven't explained why you need class `A` if you have a set of objects that are the same, but only their contained `LittleData` changes.   Why not create a single `BigData` and a collection (set, array, vector, etc) of associated `LittleData` objects?   If you have a function that needs to be passed an `A`,  create it from the (single) `BigData` and the required `LittleData` (selected by whatever criteria needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement simple copy on write with the shared_ptr. I.e. store the smart pointer on big data shared across objects of class A. And when you need to modify this big data for the specific object of A - replace the smart pointer by modified deep copy (cloned object):

I.e. something like:

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

class A {
public:
   typedef std::shared_ptr<BigData> cow_t;
   A(cow_t&& bd, const LittleData& ld):
      bd_( std::forward<cow_t>(bd) ),
      ld_(ld)
   {}
  // rule of 5 
   A(const A& c):
     bd_(c.bd_),
     ld_(c.ld_) 
   {}
   A& opertor=(const A& rhs) {
      A( rhs ).swap( *this );
      return *this;
   } 
   A(A&& c) noexcept:
     bd_( std::move(c.bd_) ),
     ld_( std::move(c.ld_) ) 
   {}
   A& operator=(A&& rhs) noexcept {
     A( std::forward<A>(rhs) ).swap( *this );
     return *this;
   }
   ~A() noexcept = default;
   void swap(A& other) {
      bd_.swap( other.bd_ );
      std::swap(ld_,other.ld_);
   } 
   // Deep copy big data when you need to modify it
   void updateBig(std::function<cow_t(cow_t&&)>  handler)  {
      return bd_ = handler( std::move(bd_) );
   }
   // Shallow copy (get the constant pointer) on big data when you simply need to read it  
   const BigData* big() const {
       return bd_.get();
   }  
   // Always deep copy for LittleData
   LittleData little() const {
      return ld_;
   }
private:
   cow_t bd_;
   LittleData ld_;
}

...
A a( std::make_shared(big), little );
a.updateBig([] (std::shared_ptr<BigData>&& data) {
  // Some deep copy (clone) before update, by copy constructor for example
  shared_ptr<BigData> update = std::make_shared( *data );
  // some modification
  update->modify();
  return update;
});
```